# NSDateFormat, super simple! Where am I screwing up?

Tags: iphone, date, formatting

Ok, this is really simple, maybe I'm a getting a bit burnt out, but seems like it should work,  Query XML feed, put out date string, format, display in a cell.  The issue is I'm a getting a NULL output.  thanks for any help!

```
// 2009-06-03 11:30:00 example
NSDate *startValue = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"start"];
NSLog(@"DATE: %@",startValue);
// outputs 2009-06-03 11:30:00

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startValue];
NSLog(@"DATE: %@", dateStr);
// outputs NULL
```

Comment: try faking startValue to see if the rest of the code works, if it does then your cell object needs massaging.

Comment: it i set it to a string, i can insert into my cell.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `startValue` is a date and not a string? Try examining its class.

Comment: Well, it's in a date format, stored as a string. It looks like a date, smells like a date, is treated as a date. hmmmmmm  That has to be the problem. Hacking it now.